# TensorFlow TPU | Initializer for variable is from a control-flow construct

Tags: python, tensorflow, tpu

I'm using TensorFlow TPUs to train a model but when I try to convert to the code to TPU compatible using tf.contrib.tpu.rewrite, I get an error:

> ValueError: Initializer for variable generator/decoder/layer4/kernel/ is from inside a control-flow construct, such as a loop or conditional. When creating a variable inside a loop or conditional, use a lambda as the initializer

I looked around, and it seems that there's usually an if-statement or while loop that causes the error. I however don't have any of these.

Now, here's the variable definition (kernel):

```
def conv1d_transpose(input, filters, kernel_size, strides, activation=None):
  kernel = tf.Variable(tf.zeros(dtype=tf.float32, shape=[kernel_size, filters, input.shape[-1].value]), name='kernel')
  output_shape = [tf.shape(input)[0], strides * tf.shape(input)[1], filters]
  net = tf.contrib.nn.conv1d_transpose(input, filter=kernel, output_shape=output_shape, stride=strides, padding='SAME')
  net = activation(net)
  return net
```

I call that function multiple times. Here's what the call looks like inside the model function:

```
  with tf.name_scope("layer4"):
    net = conv1d_transpose(
        net,
        filters=15,
        kernel_size=5,
        strides=2,
        activation=tf.nn.leaky_relu)
    net = tf.concat([net, conv4e], axis=-1)
    net = tf.layers.batch_normalization(net, training=training)
```

One more thing, before raising the error, I get a warning/error from the tpu.replicator:

> [[{{node input1}} = TPUReplicatedInputN=1, T=DT_BOOL]]
>   2018-11-02 02:55:44.242495: E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:630] Executor failed to create kernel. Not found: No registered 'TPUReplicatedInput' OpKernel for CPU devices compatible with node {{node input1}} = TPUReplicatedInputN=1, T=DT_BOOL
>       .  Registered:

However it's pretty hard to debug since it doesn't specify the name of the node that is causing the issue.

Thanks in advance.